# Mapping between SOAP messages in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, modelmapper

I have a service, implemented with Java Spring, that publishes a SOAP API. It then performs some business logic, and sends a SOAP request to another service. I currently directly map (parts of) the incoming SOAP message to the message format of the other SOAP service, so the message formats and types are quite similar. I currently use ModelMapper for this. I have two questions:

1) Should the incoming SOAP message first be mapped to an intermediate "business data model", and from there mapped to the outgoing SOAP message, or is it ok to directly map the incoming message to outgoing message without an intermediary?

2) What should I use for mapping between these two SOAP messages? I have found that ModelMapper does not necessarily do a good job automatically, and creating custom mappings becomes very difficult and time consuming. An ESB does this very nicely.